# python 'matrix' problem

Tags: python, matrix, row

I have input data(test.data)

```
4.5,3.5,U1
4.5,10.5,U2
4.5,6,U1
3.5,10.5,U2
3.5,10.5,U2
5,7,U1
7,6.5,U1
```

code I have:

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('test.data', 'r'))
result = {}
for row in reader:
    uclass=row[-1]
    if result.has_key(uclass):
        result[uclass].append(row[:-1])
    else:
        result[uclass] = row[:-1]
print result
```

Now my output is:

```
'U1': 
[['4.5', '3.5]', 
['4.5', '6'], 
['5', '7'], 
['7', '6.5'], 

'U2': 
[['4.5', '10.5'], 
['3.5', '10.5'], 
['3.5', '10.5']]
```

Where U1 and U2....is class

---

**NOW THERE IS MY PROBLEM:**
How can I now make **for loop**(or anything else), where I can call this U1, U2,....(my classes from data) and receive data.

***What I like to do is in this case:***

```
first1 = 1/3 * U1 (1/3 of data U1) = ?
first2 = 1/3 * U2 (1/3 of data U2) = ?
second1 = 2/3 * U2 (2/3 of data U1) = ?
second2 = 2/3 * U2 (2/3 of data U2) = ?
```

I need this matrix(first1,first2,second1,second2) for next calculating...

Comment: you've shown yourself capable of writing a for loop, what prevents you from doing it here?

Comment: Looks like you are posting a series of questions, each one the next step following the earlier one, regarding the same programming problem. Is this homework?

Comment: Actually, the poster is capable of copying a for loop from his previous SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444571/python-table-classification - time to start writing some of your own code now.

Comment: @thaking: Please take some time and show us an overall description on what you are aiming for! (A wild guess of mine is that you are trying to classify something, and you'll like to teach your classifier with part of your data and verify its performance with rest of the data. Correct?) Thanks

Comment: There is no description or algorithem which can be found on internet(as I think), I would like to make KLT(Karhunen in Loeve) transform of data. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karhunen%E2%80%93Lo%C3%A8ve_theorem

Comment: As I said I don't know how can I pull now daata from U1 and U2 (in my case), in other data there are a lot of classes.. and then first take 1/3 data from U1 and U2 and save to one string, and then other 2/3 ....as I write up...

Comment: @thaking: Your reference to KLT makes this issue somewhat more straightforward one. May I suggest you to ask as general as possible question about your classification needs (here or preferably in http://stats.stackexchange.com/). After understanding properly your specific requirements, we'll be able to solve the detailed implementation issues here. (Al tough, if python still remains relevant, then expecting `numpy` to be able to provide all the required functionality). Thanks

Comment: @thaking, do you know another language?

Comment: think about how you would solve the problem in c, then ask for python equivalents if you can't figure them out. You'll have better success that way.

Comment: Isn't my question clear enough ?

Comment: the problem is that the answer is too obvious. It makes you look like you aren't trying.

Comment: Well I tried 2 hours, but i didn't find any solution for what I wanted.

Comment: essentially, we are happy to help. But if we end just writing code for you, well, we prefer to be paid to do that.

Comment: I just have stuck in my problem that's all. I don't see solution for my problem. Is this really hard to understand? Now you want money. What is more important to help us in this case to me, and learn from your acknowledgements me, or to get a lot of money. In second case you are not on right place.

Comment: @thaking: as I suggested earlier; make a very clear statements of what you are trying to achieve ;-). Please note that (KLT) can be understood either (according to wiki) to be a) as `in the theory of stochastic processes, the Karhunen–Loève theorem is a representation of a stochastic process as an infinite linear combination of orthogonal functions, analogous to a Fourier series representation of a function on a bounded interval` or b) kind of `principal component analysis (PCA) can be considered to be equivalent to the discrete Karhunen–Loève transform (KLT)`. Details matters, indeed. Thanks

Comment: why is this important right now; I want to learn in this case, for this example, solution; As I said I'm also learning python. KLT is just example which I like to make with 1-NN: one nearest neighbor.

Comment: You don't learn if we write the code for you. We don't understand why you can't write this code yourself. Until we understand that, we really cannot help you.

Comment: Because i don't know solution for my problem, why you think that I'm asking and writing here????????????

Comment: For one thing, convert the strings to floats (this is covered in one of the answers to a previous question you posted). Then look at the data that you have posted, like U1: [[4.5, 3.5], [4.5, 6.0], [5.0, 7.0], [7.0, 6.5]]. What do you now mean by "first1 = 1/3 * U1 (1/3 of data U1) = ?"  1/3 the sum of all the values?  A random sampling of 1/3 of the values?  The first 1/3 of the values?  And the way to get the value for key 'U1' from your dict 'result' is `result['U1']`.

Comment: Do you understand the code that you have presented? If you do, you have everything you need to solve your problem. If you don't, then you need to learn it.

Answer (score 2):

In programming, if you don't know how to do something, break it into smaller pieces. I'm not entirely clear on what you want, so I'm going to assume its the following.

You have a list

```
x = [4.5, 6.9, 7.5, 9.2, ...]
```

You want a new list that takes the first third of that list. But you don't know how to do it. So break it down. So how do you this? Let's start with a list of instructions.

1. Create the list, y
2. Take the first item in x and put it in y
3. Take the second item in x and put it in y
4. Take the third item in x and put it in y
5. Stop when y contains the first third of items in x

Then try to follow the instructions. Firstly, how do we create an empty list in python?

```
y = []
```

Next, we need to repeat essentially the same thing a bunch of different times. How do we repeat the same action many times in python?

```
for idx in range(number of times to repeat):
```

Ok, but how many times do we need to repeat? Clearly, you want to repeat it one third of the length of x. How do we figure that out? Again, take the problem and break it down into steps

1. find the length of x
2. divide that length by 3

How do we find the length of something in python?

```
len(x)
```

How do we divide by three?

```
len(x) // 3
```

Okay, back to the loop

```
for idx in range( len(x) // 3 ):
```

Now, how take the idx element from x and put it into y? Again, let's break it down into steps:

1. Get the idxth element of x
2. Add that element to y

How do we get the idxth element of a list in python?

```
x[idx]
```

How do we add something to a list

```
y.append( object to add )
```

combine them:

```
y.append( x[idx] )
```

And thus we have the final code:

```
y = []
for idx in range( len(x) // 3 ):
    y.append( x[idx] )
```

In programming you need to be able to break down your problem into pieces that you know how to solve. If you can't do this you are probably attempting something beyond your skill level. We are happy to help if you don't know how to perform a simple task or to suggest betters of doing what you have.

Unfortunately, you case looks like someone who has been collecting magic pieces of code without understanding what the code does. I can't read your mind, I don't know if that's true. But if you want assistance, you are going to need to demonstrate what you have tried. Examples include:

1. Code that you wrote that didn't do what you wanted
2. Documentation that you read that you didn't understand
3. Discussion of your attempt to break down the problem into smaller problems

I am more then willing to help a beginning coder. I used to be one. I didn't have a resource like Stack Overflow and had to figure everything out myself. My ability to code today is probably good because nobody just gave me answers. We are happy to help you when stuck, but you seem to be stuck more then you are moving, that's the real problem here.

You keep asking us for fish, you need to learn to fish.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what exactly you aim at, but I think you should make your floats proper type

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('test.data', 'r'))
result = {}
for row in reader:
    uclass, values = row[-1], [float(item) for item in  row[:-1]]
    if uclass in result:
        result[uclass].append(values)
    else:
        result[uclass] = [values]
print(result)
```

Comment: I would like to pull U1 and U2 from data (if input data is huge than there is not just U1 and U2), and like to do this:
first1 = 1/3 * U1 (1/3 of data U1) = ?
first2 = 1/3 * U2 (1/3 of data U2) = ?
second1 = 2/3 * U2 (2/3 of data U1) = ?
second2 = 2/3 * U2 (2/3 of data U2) = ?